# Most efficient bounded maximum of high degree polynomial

Tags: calculus, numerical-optimization, numerical-calculus

Say I have identified a limit that approaches the bounded maximum value of a polynomial (with rational coefficients) to arbitrary precision.

An example such limit is:

$lim_{k->\infty} ((\int_a^b (f(x) + m)^k dx)^{(1/k)})$

Where:

- f(x) is a polynomial in x
- a,b are the bounds of the region of interest,
- m is any value larger than the minimum value of f(x) in the bounded region.

For example, plugging in $f(x) = 25 - x^2, n=1000, m=500, a=-10, b=-10$ and evaluating on wolfram alpha:

`(1000th root of (definite integral from -10 to 10 of (25 - x^2 + 500)^1000))-500` $\approx 25.13 \approx 25 $

I now want to turn the approximation of this limit into an algorithm for bounded extremum finding and understand how it compares with existing approaches. For this example, with a fixed (but potentially astronomically large) k and m, I would expect the integral could be calculated and evaluated in time roughly O(kn), where n is the length of the initial polynomial. (Roughly: total number of bits in rational coefficients)

How does this compare to other algorithms which compute global maxima within some range?  What is the best known big-O() for this calculation?

I am aware of two general methods competing with this oracle: gradient descent and factoring/root finding.

Gradient descent afaik cannot guarantee convergence beyond a local extremum, does this differ when restricted to polynomials?

How fast are factoring/root finding techniques?

Are there any other numerical techniques for this case?

Comment: What do you mean by "this calculation"?  How are you measuring the "length" of a polynomial?  What is the best method you know so far?

Comment: Over what field/ring?  $\mathbb{Q}$?  $\mathbb{R}$?  $GF(p)$?  Something else?  Does the polynomial have integer coefficients?

Comment: @D.W.  I’m thinking number of coefficients in the polynomial, though I admit that an individual enormous coefficient could throw that calculation.  Rational or real number coefficients, integer not guaranteed.  

Best methods I have heard of are listed on wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_root-finding_algorithms

Unclear if my oracle should be compared to the ones which find all roots- I don’t see any in the list that jump directly to the max, but I don’t understand them deeply.

Comment: Thanks.  Please [edit] your question so that this information is contained in the question, and so that people don't have to read the comments to understand what is being asked, and so the question reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.

Comment: I don't understand what it means to compare an explicit algorithm to an oracle.  Normally an oracle is assumed to run in $O(1)$ time or $O(n)$ time or something like that, so if you have an oracle, then it seems obvious you'd use that than some algorithm (which will take longer than $O(1)$ time).